# What is the delooping of a looping?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, loop-spaces

> What is $\mathbf{B}\Omega A$, where $A$ is a pointed object of an $(\infty,1)$ category with point $*\to A$, $\Omega A$ is the loop space of $A$, and $\mathbf{B}X$ is the delooping of $X$?

The closest I have come to finding anything about this is in [this $n$lab entry, titled *looping*](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/looping), it is mentioned that the based loop space object of $A$, i.e., $\mathbf{B}\Omega_{\mathrm{pt}}A\simeq A$.

**Edit:** How does one prove the following statement: *there is a map $\mathbf B\Omega A \to A$ which is a weak equivalence onto the connected component of the base point*, which is given in an answer by John Klein below?

Comment: Regarding your edit: look up adjoint functors, in particular the book of May [Simplicial Objects in Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/Simp.djvu) (djvu format). To echo the words of May: learn about simplicial sets and spaces first; then you can actually appreciate what is happening in the $\infty$-categorical setting.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks for the book. I'll try to read it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple example should indicate the general phenomenon: Let $A$ be a discrete based set.
The $\Omega A$ is a point, so $B \Omega A$ is a point.

The general phenomenon is this:
$B\Omega A$ is always connected, whereas $A$ needn't be. The statement which is true is that there's a map $B\Omega A \to A$ which is a weak equivalence onto the connected component of the base point.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. How could one prove the last statement? I'll add that into the question.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, look at the homotopy groups: $\Omega$ shifts them down by one (forgetting about $\pi_0$), and $B$ shifts them back up by one.

Comment: @mikeshulman Thanks for providing me with that geometrical interpretation. I understand it now!